# How can I reset my BIOS password on my Acer W3 810 Tablet

Tags: efi

I set a BIOS password on my Acer W3 810 Tablet and then forgot the password.
How can I reset my BIOS password?

Comment: Don't delete your BIOS! It will brick your tablet.

Comment: There is usually some button battery to remove that will reset your bios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the EFI System Partition does not delete any firmware settings. Your system will not be able to boot anymore, that's all. (This because the EFI System Partition contains vital boot information, including the Windows Boot Manager.)

Ask Acer for instructions on how to reset your firmware password.

Comment: what if i deleted it and reinstalled windows would my tablet work normal?

Comment: @Shuren Yes, but it still wouldn’t do anything about your firmware password.

Comment: Alright i understand sorry if I annoyed someone with this question thank you